# wget to automate HTTP download of McAfee DAT Package

Tags: download, wget

I am looking for a way to create a scheduled task to automatically download the "DAT Package For Use with McAfee ePO" [offered here](http://www.mcafee.com/apps/downloads/security-updates/security-updates.aspx). The link text on that page ("DAT Package For Use with McAfee ePO") always stays the same, but it points to a different .zip file daily, so the link target differs.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines (broken into separate lines for readability):

```
wget --execute=robots=off --recursive --level 1 --span-hosts \
--accept=.zip --no-directories --domains=download.nai.com \
http://www.mcafee.com/apps/downloads/security-updates/security-updates.aspx
```

If you're always asked to accept before being allowed to download, you'll probably have to save/load cookies. Look at the --[save|load]-cookies option to wget.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using Selenium, the browser automator. Or, if you're on a Mac, [Fake](http://fakeapp.com) might be an easier solution.

Beyond that, a curl piped to an awk piped back to xargs curl might be your best bet, but that is going to be pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement on [jáquer's answer](https://superuser.com/a/313628/22598):

```
wget --recursive --no-parent --level=1 --no-directories --reject html \
--accept-regex='avvepo.*dat.zip' --timestamping \
'http://download.nai.com/products/DatFiles/4.x/NAI/'
```

McAfee keeps the last three DAT archives in that directory, so the above command will download all three, but only if the files in the current directory are older than what's available (that's what `--timestamping` does). You'll have to do some additional scripting if you want to do something with only the latest file. But you should keep the latest three in your download directory to prevent redownloading all three files every day.